# What is the right use case for Enumerable#all? and Enumerable#each in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I keep getting confused with the use case of `Enumerable#all?` and `Enumerable#each`. For example

```
['.txt', '-hello.txt'].all? do |suffix|
        puts "temp#{suffix}"
      end
```

works for me and also

```
['.txt', '-hello.txt'].each do |suffix|
        puts "temp#{suffix}"
      end
```

works for me too.

What should i choose `.all?` or `.each` ?

Comment: Are you sure both producing same output? I think no. please re-validate. there is nothing `each?`. :(

Answer (score 5):

`all?` evaluates the block you pass to it and returns `true` if all of the elements satisfy it and `false` otherwise.

`each` is a way to iterate over the enumerable object with a block.  It will evaluate the block for *each* object.  In your case, you want to use `each`.

See the documentation for **all?** [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html) and **each** [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

Comment: Similarly `any?` returns `true` if **one** of the elements evaluates the block to `true`.

Comment: @Candide Yes, this is true.  I don't know if it's in the scope of this question though. :)

Answer (score 1):

See your code and output:

```
['.txt', '-hello.txt'].all? do |suffix|
        puts "temp#{suffix}"
end
p "======================="
['.txt', '-hello.txt'].each do |suffix|
        puts "temp#{suffix}"
end
```

Output:

```
temp.txt
"======================="
temp.txt
temp-hello.txt
```

But now the question is **why 'temp.txt' from the first code?**. Yes as `puts` returns `nil`. See below now:

```
['.txt', '-hello.txt'].all? do |suffix|
        p "temp#{suffix}"
end
p "======================="
['.txt', '-hello.txt'].each do |suffix|
        puts "temp#{suffix}"
end
```

Output:

```
"temp.txt"
"temp-hello.txt"
"======================="
temp.txt
temp-hello.txt
```

***Explanation:***

[`Enum#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) says:

> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns **true** if the block never returns **false or nil**.

Your first code `puts` returns `nil` after passing first element to the block. Block passed to `all?` will continue only when each item evaluates to `true`. Thus block returned `"temp.txt"`. Which is not the case in the second version. As `p` never returns `nil`. So the block evaluates to `true`, as all object is `true` except `nil` and `false`.